# Не устанавливаются Куки, где ошибка?

Tags: php

Не работают куки, точнее не устанавливаются даже. Работаю на Денвере. Помогите плиз.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<form action="registration/action/login.php" method="post">
Логин:<br/>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Логин" name="login" required="required"/>
  <br/>
Пароль:<br/>
<input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" name="password" required="required"/>
  <br/>
Запомните меня:<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="member"/>
  <br/>
  <br />
<a href="Index.php?id=return_pas">Восстановить пароль</a>
  <br />
  <br/>
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Вход" />
</form>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?php

include "../../config.php";

// После нажатия кнопки ВХОД:

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $login = clearData($_POST['login']);
  $password = clearData($_POST['password']);
  //$post = clearData($_POST['member']);

  // Если поля пустые:

  if (empty($login) or empty($password)) {

  $_SESSION['msg_log'] = "</br>Заполните все поля";
  header("Location:../../index.php");   
    }


  // Если не пустые:

  if (!empty($login) and !empty($password)) {

    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = ('$login') AND password = ('$password') AND activation = '1'";

    $check_data = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Mistake Check_data");

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($check_data);



    if (empty($result['id'])) {

    //если пользователя с введенным логином не существует
        $_SESSION['msg_log'] = "</br>Логин или Пароль неверный. <br> Возможно вы не активировали аккаунт.";
    header("Location:../../index.php");

}

    else {

      if (isset($_POST['member'])) {
        setcookie("login", $login, time()+3600);
        setcookie("password", $password, time()+3600);
      }


      $sess = md5(microtime());
      $sql_update = "UPDATE users SET sess='$sess' WHERE login = '$login'";
      $sql_update = mysql_query($sql_update) or die ("Mistake sql_update"); 
      $_SESSION['sess'] = $sess;

      $_SESSION['login'] = $login; // "это нужно??"
      $_SESSION['msg_log'] = "Ты вошел";
      header("Location:../../index.php");
      }  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ошибки в логе сервера есть? Что приходит в ответе в заголовках при отправлении формы в браузере? Прикладывайте эту информацию к вашему вопросу.

Comment: Нет никаких ошибок не выдает. Сайт распознает пользователя через СЕССИЮ. Но стоит закрыть браузер и заново зайти снова просит авторизации.

Comment: После нажатия кнопки Вход что-нибудь на экран выводите?

Comment: Пишет "Ты вошел". И появляются разделы доступные пользователю только после авторизации. Я вот думаю может надо как то указать директорию (путь)?? так как работаю на localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю проблема в том что нужно устанавливать cookie глобально для всех url для этого нужно задать дополнительный параметр "/":

```
    setcookie("login", $login, time()+3600, "/");
    setcookie("password", $password, time()+3600, "/");
```

Comment: Почти успел, все же спасибо)

Comment: типичная проблема, сам недавно напоролся

Answer (score 0):

**УРА Товарищи!** Решил проблему.

```
setcookie("login", $login, time()+3600, '/');
setcookie("password", $password, time()+3600, '/');
```

Не знаю механизма как это сработало, но примерно так:

мы символом `'/'` указали путь к корню нашего домена для сохранения КУКИ. А так бы она сохранялась там же где и файл обработчик (т.е. Индекс_ный файл бы ее не видел, как я понял). Возможно напутал, прочел это на англоязычном STACK и примерно так понял перевод.

3 дня потрачено чтобы вставить 1 символ в нужном месте. Добро пожаловать в Мир Программирования)

Comment: 5 и 6 параметр у функции не забывайте устанавливать, чтобы ваши логин и пароль любой js скрипт со страницы не увел. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Спасибо, не знал об этом.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cookie($key, $value = null) {

    $time = isset($value) ? time() + 3600 : -1;

    return func_num_args() > 1 ?

    setcookie($key, $value, $time, '/') :
    ($_COOKIE[$key] ?? null);
}
```

Устанавливаем

```
cookie('key', 'value');
```

Получаем значение

```
cookie('key');
```

Удаляем

```
cookie('key', null);
```